# Trying to impliment the minimax algorithm, but I get an error suggesting it cant compare a nil value to a int

Tags: lua, minimax

Here is the code I made sure to comment the minimax functions so I can make it easier for you guys to understand. I have tried to give it a go and try to understand what each bit does and I am not confident on what each step is doing or if it is doing what I want correctly.

I should say I tried following this tutorial (https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/minimax-algorithm-guide-how-to-create-an-unbeatable-ai/), I think the website did a good job about explaining how minimax works but the code used in the tutorial is written in a different language I have tried my best to convert it to my lua tic tac toe game, without the AI/minimax algorithm the game is a great 2 player game, but I wanted to challenge my self and give a go at making an ai for tic tac toe, this is how far I have gone.

```
local board_data = {top_L= " ", top_M = " ", top_R= " ", mid_L= " ", mid_M= " ", mid_R= " ", low_L= " ", low_M= " ",
low_R= " "}

local location = {"top","mid","low"}
local position = {"_L","_M","_R"}

local function find_empty_slots(board_info)
    local empty_slots = {}
    for key, value in pairs(board_info) do
        if value == " " then
            table.insert(empty_slots,key)
        end
    end
    return empty_slots
end

local function _draw_board() -- Draws the games table
    print(
    board_data["top_L"].."┃"..board_data["top_M"].."┃"..board_data["top_R"].."\n"..
    "------\n"..
    board_data["mid_L"].."┃"..board_data["mid_M"].."┃"..board_data["mid_R"].."\n"..
    "------\n"..
    board_data["low_L"].."┃"..board_data["low_M"].."┃"..board_data["low_R"].."\n"
    )
end

local function _check_if_position_exists_and_is_empty(_input) -- Checks if the user has entered a valid position and that it is empty
    return board_data[_input] == " "
end

local function _check_win_condition(current_turn) --Checks if the current player has won
    for i = 1, 3 do --Firstly checks each rows
        if board_data[location[i]..position[1]] == current_turn and board_data[location[i]..position[2]] == current_turn and board_data[location[i]..position[3]] == current_turn then
            return true --Then checks columns
        elseif board_data[location[1]..position[i]] == current_turn and board_data[location[2]..position[i]] == current_turn and board_data[location[3]..position[i]] == current_turn then
            return true 
        end -- Then checks diagonals
    if board_data[location[1]..position[1]] == current_turn and board_data[location[2]..position[2]] == current_turn and board_data[location[3]..position[3]] == current_turn then
        return true
    elseif board_data[location[3]..position[1]] == current_turn and board_data[location[2]..position[2]] == current_turn and board_data[location[1]..position[3]] == current_turn then
        return true
    end
    end
end

local function check_tie_condition()
    local is_not_empty = 0
    for i = 1,3 do
        if board_data[location[i]..position[1]] ~= " " and board_data[location[i]..position[2]] ~= " " and board_data[location[i]..position[3]] ~= " " then
            is_not_empty = is_not_empty + 3
        end
    if is_not_empty == 9 then
        return true
    end
    end
end

local function get_array_size(array)
    local count = 0
    for i in pairs(array) do
        count = count + 1
    end
    return count
end

local function minimax(board,current_player) -- MINIMAX ai
    local empty_slots = find_empty_slots(board) -- Finds the empty slots on the tic tac toe board

    if _check_win_condition("X")then --Checks if someone has won,lost, or draw
        return -1
    elseif _check_win_condition("O") then
        return 1
    elseif empty_slots == 0 then
        return 0
    end

    local all_test_plays = {} --Stores all the plays of the ai
    for i = 1, get_array_size(empty_slots) do -- Loops 
        local current_test_play = {} --a current fake/test play of the game
        current_test_play["Index"] = empty_slots[i] --Creates a key called Index and sets the empty slots key to it, the keys are strings, check board data to understand
        board_data[empty_slots[i]] = current_player --Sets the empty slot to the current player which would be ai for the moment
        if current_player == "O" then -- Checks whos playing and apply the minimax function again to produce a recursion
            local result = minimax(board_data,"X") -- Get the result from going again in the board
            current_test_play["Score"] = result -- Then saves the result to a new key called score
        else
            local result = minimax(board_data,"O")
            current_test_play["Score"] = result
        board_data[empty_slots[i]] = " " -- We set the slots index to a blank/empty when done
        table.insert(all_test_plays,current_test_play) -- Insert the current_test_play to all test_plays to compare
        end
    
    local best_play = nil -- a place to store the best play for the ai
    local best_score = nil -- stores the best score aswell
    if current_player == "O" then -- O is the ai in this case
        best_score = -1000 -- Not sure why I need to do this, I followed some tutorial written in a different language that used infinity which I assumed it just a big number
        for i = 1, get_array_size(all_test_plays) do -- Loop through all the plays avaliable
            if all_test_plays[i]["Score"] > best_score then -- compare to see if the score is better then best_score once again i dont have a clue
                best_score = all_test_plays[i]["Score"] --Seting the score and play
                best_play = all_test_plays[i]["Index"]
            end
        end
    else
        best_score = 1000 -- pretty much a  copy and past from the top except its not negative
        for i = 1, get_array_size(all_test_plays) do
            print(all_test_plays[i]["Score"])
            if all_test_plays[i]["Score"] < best_score then --THIS IS ERROR LINE 107
                best_score = all_test_plays[i]["Score"]
                best_play = all_test_plays[i]["Index"]
            end
    end
    end
    return best_play -- we return it so this would be the best play the ai would make I think.
end
end

local function _game() --The main loop of the game
    local current_turn = "X" -- it holds two states X or O
    print("Please select a position from the board, to access the top row, type top_position position being L, M , R e.g top_L \n")
    _draw_board()
    while true do
        print("Player " ..current_turn.. " is selected!")
        if current_turn == "O" then -- Checks if its Os turn/AI and make it play the minimax function
            local play = minimax(board_data,"O")
            print(play)
            current_turn = "X"
        else -- Else its the players turn
            local Input = io.read()
        if _check_if_position_exists_and_is_empty(Input) then
            board_data[Input] = current_turn
            _draw_board()
            if _check_win_condition(current_turn) then
                print("Player "..current_turn .. " Has won this game!")
                break
            elseif check_tie_condition() then
                print("The game has ended at a tie!")
                break
            end
            if current_turn == "X" then -- Switch to the other player
                current_turn = "O"
            elseif current_turn == "O" then
                current_turn = "X"
            end
            
        else
            print("\nThat wasnt a command in the table or the slot wasnt empty!, example top_L, mid_R, low_M \n")
        end
    end
end
        end
        

_game()
```

Here is the error I received, I also tried including some of the print statements that I put trying to figure out why it didnt do things correctly, or maybe I forgot to do something. I have also commented on which line the error , error-ed out

```
Player O is selected!
-1
nil
lua: /mnt/1TB SSD/Lua Projects/Tic Tac Toe/main.lua:107: attempt to compare nil with number
stack traceback:
        /mnt/1TB SSD/Lua Projects/Tic Tac Toe/main.lua:107: in upvalue 'minimax'
        /mnt/1TB SSD/Lua Projects/Tic Tac Toe/main.lua:84: in upvalue 'minimax'
        /mnt/1TB SSD/Lua Projects/Tic Tac Toe/main.lua:87: in upvalue 'minimax'
        /mnt/1TB SSD/Lua Projects/Tic Tac Toe/main.lua:84: in upvalue 'minimax'
        /mnt/1TB SSD/Lua Projects/Tic Tac Toe/main.lua:124: in local '_game'
        /mnt/1TB SSD/Lua Projects/Tic Tac Toe/main.lua:153: in main chunk
        [C]: in ?
The terminal process "bash '-c', 'lua '/mnt/1TB SSD/Lua Projects/Tic Tac Toe/main.lua''" terminated with exit code: 1.
```

Comment: You've made some major changes to the tutorial's algorithm without fully understanding it. You might have to go through the whole `minimax` function and rewrite it to match the tutorial more precisely.

Comment: replying to the first comment: Thats how they are supposed to be, if they return true then the function ends there else it continues down into the function. Second comment: I will try to go through each line slowly so I can understand better, thank you for telling me!

Comment: I couldn't figure out why it keeps returning a nil, its as close as possible to the tutorial code, so I am confused!

Comment: One major difference that I noticed is that the tutorial's `minimax` returns an object that can have fields `score` and `index`. Your `mimimax` tries to sometimes return a score, other times an index, but never both. Another major difference is you've put `end`s in places that don't match the original.

Answer (score 0):

I won't do all the debugging for you, but at some point table `all_test_plays` is empty.

This causes `minimax`'s return value `best_play` to become nil as the loop that could assign a value to it is not run due to the empty table.

This is then assigned to the `Score` field which later is compared vs a number.

Your logic seems to be broken. Go back through your code and compare it with the tutorial's code. Most importantly make sure you understand what this algorithm is doing. you should be able to do the same with pen and paper. Ensure that your "AI" is doing what you would do. At some point there will be a difference.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it another go, trying to map each stage of the code .